# Redirecting to checkout after account is created and products are in cart

Tags: magento

I have a special case where users have to sign up for an account via the account sign up page (e.g. /customer/account/create/). Upon completion, and in the event that they have a product in the cart, I need to redirect them back to the checkout screen.

I currently have an observer in place that listens to the `customer_register_success` event. The observer upgrades the users account to a membership group via this code:

```
class Hatclub_MembershipHandler_Model_Observer {

    // members group id
    const GROUP_ID = 4;

    // called when a customer registers for the site
    public function registrationSuccess(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

        // extract customer data from event
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();

        // a cookie should have been set with the membership id
        if (isset($_COOKIE['membership_account_id'])) {

            $customer
                ->setGroupId(self::GROUP_ID)
                ->setRmsId($_COOKIE['membership_account_id']);

        }

        return $this;

    }

}
```

Is there another event that I can listen to that is better suited for what I want to do? I have a redirect_to cookie that is available as well if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial and error, I came across a solution. Since I'm already using the `customer_register_success` event and modifying user data with my observer, I had to use another event called `customer_save_after` and it worked like a charm.

**config.xml event block**

```
<customer_save_after>
    <observers>
        <customer_session_observer>
            <class>hatclub_membership_handler/observer</class>
            <method>customerSave</method>
            <type>singleton</type>
        </customer_session_observer>
    </observers>
</customer_save_after>
```

**observer.php method**

```
public function customerSave() {

        // set redirect url from cookie, default to null
        $redirect_url = (isset($_COOKIE['redirect_url'])) 
            ? isset($_COOKIE['redirect_url']) : null;

        // if a redirect url was specified
        if (isset($redirect_url)) {

            // remove cookie to prevent infinite loop
            unset($_COOKIE['redirect_url']);

            // redirect to provided url
            Mage::app()->getResponse()
              ->setHeader('Location', $redirect_url)
              ->sendHeaders();

        }

}
```

The redirect within an observer was a bit of a struggle, but I managed to accomplish it using

```
Mage::app()->getResponse()
    ->setHeader('Location', $redirect_url)
    ->sendHeaders();
```

Suggestions and criticism welcome.